# Code for "finding and deleting" complete strings but not substrings in R?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am trying to find a way of quickly cleaning large datasets based on the occurrence of certain strings. I have a data.frame that looks like this:

```
created_at  actor_attributes_email      type
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch         Event
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch         PushEvent
3/11/12 7:28    jeremy@asynk.ch         PushEvent
3/11/12 7:42    jeremy@asynk.ch         IssueCommentEvent
3/11/12 11:06   d.bussink@gmail.com     PushEvent
3/11/12 11:06   d.bussink@gmail.com     PushEvent
```

You can find the complete CSV [here](https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/rubinius_rubinius_sequencing/input.csv).

I am writing commands for "find and delete in R":

```
# Load CSV file
events.raw <- read.csv(file = "input.csv", header = TRUE)

# Delete events called "Event"
events.raw.new <- events.raw[!grepl("Event", events.raw$type, fixed = TRUE),]
```

My code now deletes every line, and I'm not quite sure, since I am using the fixed = TRUE argument. What I want is to delete all the rows where "Event" is the complete string, since it is a substring in every row. How can I restrict my code to complete strings?

Comment: why not just do
`events.raw.new <- events.raw[events.raw$type != 'Event']`?

If you insist on the RegEx, go with `'^Event$'` as the matching string.

Answer (score 0):

One answer to the question is:

```
events.raw <- subset(events.raw, type!="Event")
```

However, this does not solve the problem of

```
events.raw.new <- events.raw[!grepl("Event", events.raw$type, fixed = TRUE),]
```

not achieving the same purpose.

Comment: Your second line is matching all lines with "Event" in them anywhere still. You would need to restrict to "Event" only with nothing before or after. `events.raw[!grepl("^Event$",events.raw$type),]`